# allow duplicates within x axis of a histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, duplicates, histogram

I would like to draw a histogram with Frequency as the x axis and variableAmount as the y axis, I would also like to allow duplicate values within the x axis. I am using the following code which does not allow duplicate values within the x axis as you can see:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

variableAmount = [16,20,21,10,12,25,9,13,7,6,5,8,4,3,2,1,0]
Frequency = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','4','4','7','11','12','13','62','105','464','1726','14775'] #sample names


plt.bar(Frequency, variableAmount)
plt.xlabel('Number of Methods')
plt.ylabel('Variables')
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting graph I obtain, as you can see 2, 4 and 1 each appear only once within the x axis of the histogram, which is wrong since 1 appears 3 times, 2 appears 3 times and 4 appears 2 times within the Frequency array specified in my code (['1','1','1','2','2','2','4','4'...]). How can I fix this and allow duplicated values within the x axis of my histogram?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all plotted but some smaller bars are covered by the larger ones because some are plotted at the same position. Maybe a little detour will help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

variableAmount = [16,20,21,10,12,25,9,13,7,6,5,8,4,3,2,1,0]
Frequency = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','4','4','7','11','12','13','62','105','464','1726','14775'] #sample names
helper = np.arange(len(Frequency))

plt.bar(helper, variableAmount)
plt.xticks(ticks=helper, labels=Frequency, rotation=45)

plt.xlabel('Number of Methods')
plt.ylabel('Variables')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

But what does it mean that `1` has multiple values? I don't know.

Comment: it's not working: AttributeError: Unknown property ticks

Comment: [Why would that be?](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) You can omit the keywords, but it does not make sense that your matplotlib version complains about it. Unless you run a pre 3.1 version of matplotlib. In this case, you should specify in your question what version you use.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 on Spyder 3.3.1

Comment: matplotlib: 2.2.3

Comment: I suggest you put this into the question. We are now at 3.3.3. Either you update your matplotlib or wait for somebody who still works with this outdated version.